# Bash on Windows - debug a python file with Visual Code or Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a python file in my Bash on Windows environment.
Is it possible to debug it with Visual Code or Visual Studio?

Can a debugger be attached to the Linux python version that exists in the Bash on Windows environment?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a few options for this. If you're attempting to debug a python file that's saved on your home directory in Bash on Windows, you can navigate to your home directory in Windows by going to "C:\Users\[windows username]\AppData\Local\lxss\home\[ubuntu username]\". Then you can open any of your projects or files saved on your home folder in Ubuntu. You can even make a shortcut on your desktop or something to make it easier to access this folder.

However, if you need the environment that you have on Bash for dependencies or python modules, your other option is to install a GUI and Linux-compatible IDE of your preference on Ubuntu, and use Xming on Windows to run the IDE on your screen. A tutorial on how to do this can be found [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/261575/how-to-run-graphical-linux-desktop-applications-from-windows-10s-bash-shell/).

If you need to debug a linux python program from Visual Studio, a simple Google search yielded [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-cross-platform-remote). I haven't tried it but this seems to be the solution you are looking for. For connecting over the network to Bash on Windows from Windows, use localhost for the host.

Comment: Thanks but I am specifically looking for a way to debug the scripts from windows ide and not through linux gui.

Comment: I googled and found a solution for using Visual Studio, but why are you dead set on using VS? As you can see, it's limited for developing on other operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to just move the file. Your normal windows system is mounted under `/mnt/c`.

You can just copy it to your desktop by doing

`cp (path to your file) /mnt/c/(your username)/Desktop`

When you need to access or edit it from bash, just `cd` to that location (or wherever else you choose to store it).

Interesting other idea: you could mount cloud storage (e.g. google drive) via fuse in linux then set it up in windows. Copy the python to it and you can edit in windows and access in linux as needed. (Google is your friend here; look into google-drive-ocamlfuse or gdrivefs).

Hope this helps!

jBit

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making use of the ***Remote - WSL*** extension for Visual Studio code. It allows you to easily access your Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and use it as a full-time dev environment.

Here is an article on how to [set up Visual Studio Code Remote-WSL](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl).

After that is set up, you can quickly load your python file in the VS Code editor using a command like: `code path/to/python_file.py`